# Unity3D does sprite sheet automatically batched?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know I can use sprite packer to pack sprites so that there will be only one drawCall. If I slice a sprite sheet into multiple sprites, will it have the same effect? I experimented on my own, but there is no batching saved and I am afraid I did something wrong?

I used UI Image. And I used same material on them to hope batch them.

Answer (score 0):

You may open the [Frame Debugger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrameDebugger.html) to inspect whether your sprites are batched.

See also [DrawCallBatching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html) for more details on when and how draw-calls will be batched.

Comment: In frame debugger, it shows only one draw call, i guess the reason is that "saved by batch" only shows those optimized by Unity engine , but UI image draw call is optimzed by UI code not by the engine?